# When trying to convert files in FileInputStream i got a FileNotFound Exception

Tags: java

i am trying to convert .wav files to FileInputStream. These .wav files are located on the server. This sever is accessible only by given IP address. these .wav files are successfully playing when i hit them on chrome. But at the conversion time the java code is giving me FileNotFoundException. how can I solve this problem ? thank you.

**following URL is one of them**

```
https:\\192.168.1.252\\monitor_wav\\OUT7048-20180503-083949-1525316989.211806.wav
```

**following is my code to convert file**

```
   try {
        File fl = new File("https:\\192.168.1.252\\monitor_wav\\OUT7048-20180503-083949-1525316989.211806.wav");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**i am facing the following error**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:\192.168.1.252\monitor_wav\OUT7048-20180503-083949-1525316989.211806.wav (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at com.transfer.conn.Test.wavToStream(Test.java:19)
at com.transfer.conn.Test.main(Test.java:25)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from HTTPS server using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135074/download-file-from-https-server-using-java)

Comment: i am not downloading files. I am converting them.

Comment: `FileInputStream` is for files in a local file system, not files on a remote server accessed via http(s). Hence accessing a file via http(s) is downloading.

Comment: `File` does not support HTTP/HTTPS... in order to do this, you either need to download the file to a local storage then convert it, or do it on the fly while downloading, in all cases you need a code to download the file, example, you can use `Apache Commons IO` library as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698213/3604083

Comment: i got it :-) i need to first download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

---

```
try {
                URL url = new URL("https:\\192.168.1.252\\monitor_wav\\OUT7048-20180503-083949-1525316989.211806.wav");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: thank you very much vaibhav Singh. i got the solution from you.

Answer (score -2):

normally in java audio files are handled by:-

```
try {
     File fileIn = new File(somePathName);
     AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
}catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question